# How many positive integer(s) x is / are there so that $\sqrt{x^2 + 4x + 670}$ is an integer?

Tags: number-theory

How many positive integer(s) x is / are there so that $\sqrt{x^2 + 4x + 670}$  is an integer?

I can do it up till the completing the square portion. However, the (u+x+2)(u-x-2) messes me up.

Comment: What is $u$?  You need parentheses to show the whole expression is under the square root sign.  Better yet, use MathJax as shown in the FAQ.  What did you get when you tried to complete the square?

Comment: Is is so right?

Comment: I think the close and down votes are too harsh. OP clearly tried, although they did not communicate thier attempt very clearly.

Comment: @YiFan sorry i didn't realise :( I added more stuff into it now

Comment: @RossMillikan sorry i didn't realise :/ i added more stuff into it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $u=\sqrt{x^2+4x+670}$. Then,
$$u^2=x^2+4x+4+666\\u^2=\left(x+2\right)^2+666\\u^2-\left(x+2\right)^2=666$$
However, we know that the integers that is $2 \mod 4$ can't be expressed as the difference of two perfect square, and $666\equiv 2\pmod{4}$, so there are no solution for $x$.

**Explanation of integers that is $2 \mod 4$ can't be expressed as the difference of two perfect square:**

First, we need to prove that any perfect squares can only be $0 \mod 4$ or $1\mod 4$.

Let $n^2$ be the perfect square.

If $n$ is odd, let $n=2k+1$ and $k$ is an integer, then

$$n^2=\left(2k+1\right)^2=4k^2+4k+1=4\left(k^2+k\right)+1$$
Therefore, $n^2\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ when $n$ is odd.

If $n$ is even, let $n=2m$ and $m$ is an integer, then
$$n^2=\left(2m\right)^2=4m^2$$
Therefore, $n^2\equiv 0 \pmod 4$ when $n$ is even.

After that, we can show that for any two integers $m,n$, $m^2-n^2$ must not be $2\mod4$.

We can make a table to find the possibilities of $m^2-n^2$ in modular $4$.
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
    m^2\mod 4&n^2\mod 4&m^2-n^2\mod 4\\  \hline
0&0&0\\  
   \hline
0&1&-1\\  \hline
1&0&1\\ \hline
1&1&0\\ \hline
\end{array}$$
Therefore, it is impossible to find an integer that is $2 \mod 4$ can be expressed as the difference of two perfect square.

Comment: Oh, I don't know how to do modulars... so the answer is 0?

Comment: Yes, you are correct @SadBanana